# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC - returning IEnumerable to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm really really rusty in ASP.NET MVC so go easy on me.

You'll have to imagine the UI - 2 date pickers and a submit button. User selects two dates. On submit the dates are used in a query to the backend database. Ideally I'd like the data to be displayed on the same view. So far, the view looks something like this :

```
@model loyalty_rpm_reports.Models.TransactionCriteria
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">RPM - Failed Transactions</h1>

    <fieldset> 
        @using (Html.BeginForm("FailedTransactions", "Transactions", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
            <p>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.StartDate)
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.StartDate)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.StartDate)

                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EndDate)
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.EndDate)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EndDate)
                
            </p>    
            <p>
                <button type="submit">Retrieve Data!</button>
            </p>
        }
        
        <!--TO DO results table to go here-->

    </fieldset>  
</div>
```

The model being used by the view is `TransactionCriteria` - this is simply to store user inputted dates from the view. `TransactionCriteria` is passed to the controller:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace loyalty_rpm_reports.Models
{
    public class TransactionCriteria
    {
        // Both StartDate and EndDate are nullable (DateTime?) otherwise the properties have 
        // a value by default (01/01/0001) so validation passes

        [Display(Name = "Select Start Date")]
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Select End Date")]
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set;}
    }
}
```

On submit the controller action `FailedTransactions` is called and queries the database. I can successfully query the database.

My question is this: how do I display the data in my view? Of course I could pass my `IEnumerable` containing the results back to the view and display in a table, but then I'd have to have a second `@model` in said view, which is not allowed. Again - new to this so go easy - kind(ish) suggestions welcome!

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult FailedTransactions(TransactionCriteria transCriteria_)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
     {
         return View(); 
     }

     // return top 10 for now - eventually use transCriteria_.StartDate and 
     // transCriteria_.EndDate to query database
     IEnumerable<ImportHistory> objHistoryList = _db.tblRPM_History.Take(10);

     // Can't do the following because I'd have to put another @model in the view
     // return view(objHistoryList)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with ViewData/ViewBag or create a ViewModel which contains all data you need then return view with the viewmodel

`ViewData["SomeKey"]=objHistoryList`; / `ViewBag.SomeKey=objHistoryList`

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0#pass-data-to-views) for more details

Comment: Thanks - thats super cool!  I used the existing model the view uses to capture user input data and added database results to ViewData, which I was then able to iterate through and display in my view.